# How do I change this controller to take multiple records, usinv the ASP.Net MVC Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a booking app, which accepts a single "booking" object, and works ok.  My question is, how do I convert this to accept multiple records (from JSON):

Booking.cs

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class Booking
    {
        [Key()]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long? HID { get; set; }
        public long RID { get; set; }
        public string Occ { get; set; }
        public DateTime CI { get; set; }
        public DateTime CO { get; set; }
        public long? CID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

BookingsContext.cs

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class BookingsContext : DbContext
    {
    public BookingsContext() : base("name=BookingsContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

BookingsController.cs

```
    // POST api/Bookings
        public HttpResponseMessage PostBooking(Booking booking)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    // Add the booking
                    db.Bookings.Add(booking);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, booking);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = booking.RID }));
                    return response;
                }
            }
```

The JSON currently passed is:

```
var comment = {ID:0, HID: $('#HID').val(), RID:$('#RID').val(), Occ:$('#Occ').val(), CI:$('#CI').val(), CO:$('#CO').val(), CID:$('#CID').val()},{ID:0, HID: $('#HID').val(), RID:$('#RID').val(), Occ:$('#Occ').val(), CI:$('#CI').val(), CO:$('#CO').val(), CID:$('#CID').val()};
```

How can I pass multiple records to the controller, so that I don't have to call the JSON Post method may times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the signature of your action to take an array of Booking:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostBooking(Booking[] bookings)
{
    ...
}
```

and then send an array of booking from the client:

```
var bookings =
    [
        {
            ID: 0,
            HID: 'hid1',
            RID: 'rid1',
            Occ: 'occ1',
            CI: 'ci1',
            CO: 'co1',
            CID: 'cid1'
        },
        {
            ID: 1,
            HID: 'hid2',
            RID: 'rid2',
            Occ: 'occ2',
            CI: 'ci2',
            CO: 'co2',
            CID: 'cid2'
        }
    ];
```

Comment: hi - how do you loop round this array, once it's been sent to the controller: foreach (var bkg in booking.Count[])
                  {
                  }  doesn't work. Thanks, Mark